# Iterating all elements in paging enabled GridView control and saving all at once

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a `<asp:GridView>` control on a page which shows a list of elements. I have enabled the paging for control `AllowPaging="True"`. There are TextBoxes for a property of column and other details are read only. I want to make changes in all the elements text field and want to save all at once based on a condition.

Now my issue is due to enabled paging, when I click on save changes on any page, `List.Rows` return only elements on the current page and not on all pages. Another issue I found is if I make changes on first page,go to second page and make changes and come to first page, the changes I made are gone, so probably even my first issue gets solved, it will remain as issue. Can anyone please suggest what changes could be made to make this scenario work?

Below is the sample code for reference.
**ASPX :**

```
<asp:GridView Id="foo" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="bar">
.
.
    <Columns>
    .
    .
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox /> //This is editable and I need to save all items at once
                .
                .
                .
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
.
.
<asp:GridView>
.
.
<asp:objectdatasource ID="bar" .... />
<asp:Button ID="savechanges" . . . . />
```

**VB**

```
Protected Sub savechanges_Click(....)
.
.
    For Each element in foo.Rows  //Here I get only current page rows, not all, plus when I go to next page, previous pages value flushes.
        baz.Property = textbox.value //For sample, reading value for calculation
    Next

    Calc() //Some way to calculate all changed values

    If pass Then
        Save()
    Else
        Cancel()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. The GridView only contains the amount of rows visible on the page. So when paging, store the changes of that page in some temp data like a `List<class>` or `DataTable` and reload the GridView from there when paging. 
That way you have all the changes and can save them all at once by iterating the items in the dataset.

Or you can save the changes per page instead of all at once. That will work.

Comment: I created a property to save all values in a viewstate and on page index changed, I updated those values... This works well when I go through the pages and save at end. But when I revisit the page where I've changed some value, it is reset from the objectdatasource( this is my thought about why it is reset) .

Comment: updated question with including objectdatasource too. It's select is dependent on a dropdown's value... when the page is changed, I guess this data is getting loaded ( even though dropdown value is not changed, but the source remains same while doing the manipulation operations)